# Refresh API KEY in AWS Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-gateway

In AWS Gateway we've got usage plans in which we set up requests limit and api keys which are bound to some usage plans. Is there any option just to refresh api key and keep the same old quota without creating usage plan?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot update API-Key value.**
If I understand your question correctly, you want to rotate API-Key.

For that you have to

- [Delete API-Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_DeleteApiKey.html)
- [Create new API-Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_CreateApiKey.html)
- [Create usagePlanKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_CreateUsagePlanKey.html) with newly created API-Key